# How to fetch data in below format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
 ___________
| id | date |
 -----------
```

with values like

```
1, 2012-02-21 04:04:04
2, 2012-02-21 05:03:05
3, 2012-02-22 03:03:03
```

Now, ask is to have a query which fetches 1 id/day which is corresponding to lower date
so, in this case query should return

```
id
---
1
3
```

// for date=2012-02-21, there are 2 rows, so row with id 1 is selected due to lower date value
// for date=2012-02-22, there is only 1 row, so corresponding id is picked

(Sorry for not a descriptive title)

Comment: [What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand, do you mean the results should be 1 and 2 (by id) when you filter by '2012-02-21'

Comment: Please clearify. What do you mean? Do you mean a single day (like 21 february). This doesn't correspond to rows 1 and 3 beeing on two different days (21 february and 22 february).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            `id`
            ORDER BY
                `date` ASC SEPARATOR ','
        ),
        ',',
        1
    ) AS `id`
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    DATE(`date`)
```